# Sequelize raw query selector group some part in array

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This is my code in sequelize
Shortly, what I want is to make an array out of some part of data. I need to add even more arrays inside an array as a value of an object. I can't make a model because I'm trying to make a program out of an existing program that i've previously written. My tables' column names and structure is not appropriate to ORM

```
const mainAndLastGroups = await sequelize.query(
    `
    SELECT
        MG.LOGICALREF AS [id], 
        MG.CODE AS [code],
        MG.NAME AS [name],
        LG.LOGICALREF AS [lastGroups.id],
        LG.CODE AS [lastGroups.code],
        LG.NAME AS [lastGroups.name]
    FROM
        ITEMS AS MG
        LEFT JOIN ITEMS AS LG ON LG.CARDTYPE = 1 
        AND LG.SPECODE = 'ALT GRUP' 
        AND LG.ACTIVE = 0 
        AND MG.CODE = LEFT ( LG.CODE, LEN( MG.CODE ) ) 
    WHERE
        MG.CARDTYPE = 1 
        AND MG.SPECODE = 'ANA GRUP'
`,
    {
        nest: true,
        type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
    }
);
```

it returns:

```
[ {
    "id": 5140,
    "code": "03",
    "name": "YUMSAK MEBEL",
    "lastGroups": {
        "id": 5141,
        "code": "03B01",
        "name": "KOL BAGLANTI PLASTIK"
    }
},
{
    "id": 5140,
    "code": "03",
    "name": "YUMSAK MEBEL",
    "lastGroups": {
        "id": 5145,
        "code": "03D01",
        "name": "DERI URUNLER"
    }
},
{
    "id": 5140,
    "code": "03",
    "name": "YUMSAK MEBEL",
    "lastGroups": {
        "id": 5150,
        "code": "03K01",
        "name": "KOL USTU AHSAP"
    }
}]
```

i want it to return:

```
[ {
"id": 5140,
"code": "03",
"name": "YUMSAK MEBEL",
"lastGroups": [{
    "id": 5141,
    "code": "03B01",
    "name": "KOL BAGLANTI PLASTIK"
},
{
    "id": 5145,
    "code": "03D01",
    "name": "DERI URUNLER"
},
{
    "id": 5150,
    "code": "03K01",
    "name": "KOL USTU AHSAP"
}]}]
```

Comment: Did you managed to make it work ?